# react-native-vector-icon show "wrong" icon

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I'm using `react-native-vector-icons` for my React native project. Recently when I open my app, it keep showing the wrong icon that i was filled in the `name` field or its show that this icon is not exist ("question mark").

I feel really awkward because it just normal in about one or two week later. I keep searching from SOF or their github but feel like no hope.

Can you help me with this.

```js
<Icon
    containerStyle={{
        display: (this.state.email.length > 0) ? 'flex' : 'none',
        marginRight: normalize(10),
    }}
    name="mail-outline"
    type="ionicon"
    color="#7384B4"
    size={22}
    onPress={() => {
        this.setState({ email: '' });
    }}
/>
```

This is my code, it suppose to show the mail icon, but I`ve got this
[image]

and this is some related dependency version I've been used in my `package.json`

```
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.3",
"react-native-elements": "^1.2.0",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^7.0.0",
```

Thanks and have a great day.

Answer (score 4):

Follow this process:

1. Open the following file:
   ProjectDir/android/app/build.gradle
2. Add the line at the end of the file:

```
apply from:("../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle");
```

3. Run the command:
   `yarn start --reset-cache`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. It's related to manually linking vs autolinking (new version)

[Details on autolinking](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md)

Solution:
`npx react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons`
`npm run android`

npm run android actually runs: `react-native run-android`

Answer (score 1):

You should declare `import Icon` in specific way,

example: `import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'`

e.g:

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
//or you can use
//import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'

//usage

<Icon
    //containerStyle={{
        //display: (this.state.email.length > 0) ? 'flex' : 'none',
        //marginRight: normalize(10),
    //}}
    //i think it should be `style` not `containerStyle`
    //except you are using another lib to show icon
    style={{
        display: (this.state.email.length > 0) ? 'flex' : 'none',
        marginRight: normalize(10),
    }}
    name="mail-outline"
    color="#7384B4"
    size={22}
    onPress={() => {
        this.setState({ email: '' });
    }}
/>

//another way
//<Ionicons
//{...all props you need to define}
///>
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by outdated icons font files, you may have updated the package version but not the font files. Try to recopy font files from 'Fonts' folder.

https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/tree/master/Fonts